majority of + noun/ pronoun + plural verb
majority, bus and photo are all singular nouns.
We say The bus of students is going. but The majority of students are going.
Similarly, we say A photo of us is here., but also The majority of us are here.
Any logic behind this?

We don't say the bus of students! You could say the busload of students or the bus filled with students. The majority of is another way of saying most of - it refers to a number of people.

I assume the main question is whether majority (of) takes a singular or plural verb. If so, there are other answers: See for example here and here.

"Majority" can be used both as a singular and plural noun.
